# UltraLiteJ Error[-1305]: MobiLink communication error -- code: 201, parameter: 128, system code: 0 Error

Tags: android, sup, mobilink

I am getting

```
UltraLiteJ Error[-1305]: MobiLink communication error -- code: 201, parameter: 128, system code: 0
```

error while synchronizing with SUP server some time synchronization takes place but most of the time i am getting this error.. please help

Note: I am synchronizing from android application

Comment: You should mention the client library version you are using for your application.

Answer (score 2):

According to the SUP help [link](http://dcx.sybase.com/index.html#1201/en/saerrors/sa-errors-by-sqlcode.html), 1305 corresponds to MobiLink communication error -- code: %1, parameter: %2, system code: %3.

Now according to mobilink communication error help [link](http://dcx.sybase.com/index.html#1201/en/saerrors/mlcommerr201.html) the error is
Timed out trying to read %1 bytes

So the actual error is "Timed out trying to read 128 bytes". 
Generally this problem is caused by network issues.